# Windows 10 new install login differences

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

I have a laptop (Win10Prox64, v1909) and a desktop (Win10Prox64, v2004). The desktop I recently built and as I was installing Windows 10 on it I think I set up a local account to start, then later attached it to my MS login.

When I log in to the laptop, I get a screen that looks like this:

[image: Laptop Login Screen]

However, when I log into my Desktop, I see a different set of login screens.

[image]

When I click the "Sign In" text, I get this screen:

[image]

This appears to ping the MS server somehow and one time when I booted into Safe Mode without Networking I got stuck because I couldn't login (without networking it wasn't able to ping the server to check the pw) and I couldn't tell Windows that I didn't want to be in Safe Mode any more, so eventually all I could do was format and start again.

I have no idea what these differences are, which are better, and if I should be concerned. I'm also not sure if this is somehow related to another problem that I'm having. When I reboot my system some of my software is getting a little fishy. For example, my VPN software won't connect to the correct server. I happened into my Users folder the other day and found a bunch of weird directories hanging out in there.

[image]

Again, I have no idea if these things are related, but I thought I should try to mention everything in case I'm missing something. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: So what came out of reinstalling Windows?  What versions of Windows 10 are each machine running exactly?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: “I happened into my Users folder the other day and found a bunch of weird directories hanging out in there” - There is nothing strange about those user profiles, they were created, when Windows was unable to use the proper profile.  That matches up to your problem with your VPN software.  If you diagnose your VPN software with your IT Administrator then you will resolve the profile problem (and thus solve the logon screen problem).  Why exactly are the user profiles on a different disk, user profiles, typically are on the system disk not a secondary data disk.

Comment: Updated at the very top of the post.

Comment: Sadly this is my home, so there isn't an IT Administrator to discuss it with. I moved the users folder to the D drive. I've done this before, but it has never created multiple extra users folders before. Nor has it created this strange login on my previous desktop which I had configured the same way.

Comment: The default user profile is used when your actual user profile cannot be used.  This indicates a network communication problem.  The differences in the logon screen are due to the fact are running 1909 on one machine and 2004 on another.  However, that desktop screenshot still isn't correct.  "For example, my VPN software won't connect to the correct server." - The reinstall did not resolve this problem?

Comment: I don't have a sense that there is a network communication problem before or during login, though I'm not sure how to verify that.

Comment: You indicated you are having problems connecting to your VPN server.  **That indicates to me there is a network problem.**

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing after switching to a new laptop with 20H2 preinstalled. Slows down the login process drastically, very annoying. My network is in good shape though, and the old 1909 laptop logins normally.